# Functions with other functions as input using delegates in C#

Tags: c#, delegates, lambda, anonymous-function

I have some delegates and a method:

```
delegate Point Translate(Point p);
delegate Translate Transform(Translate t);

Translate forward = p => new Point(p.X + 1, p.Y);
```

**Question:** How can I implement a method like this:

```
Transform Rotate90 = ??
```

So that `Rotate90` rotates any `Translate` function 90 clockwise. So:

```
Point startPoint = new Point(1, 1);
Point endPoint = (Rotate90(forward))(startPoint);
//desired output: Point(1, 0)
```

**EDIT 1:**
I'm not going to apply `Translate` functions one by one on a point. What I need is to apply some transformed functions (`Translate` function that have been rotated or reflexed) on a point.

**WHAT I NEED:** How can I write a `Rotate90` which if I pass it `(p=>new Point(p.X+1, p.y))` it returns me a function with the same effect as `(p=>new Point(p.X, p.Y-1))`.

**EDIT 2:** Some examples:

```
Translate forward =         p => new Point(p.X + 1, p.Y);
Translate backward =        p => new Point(p.X - 1, p.Y);
Translate downward =        p => new Point(p.X, p.Y - 1);
Translate runningForward =  p => new Point(p.X + 5, p.Y);

Transform Rotate90Cw = ??

Point samplePoint = new Point(1, 1);

Point p1 = (Rotate90Cw(forward))(samplePoint);          //must be (1,0)
Point p2 = (Rotate90Cw(backward))(samplePoint);         //must be (1,2)
Point p3 = (Rotate90Cw(downward))(samplePoint);         //must be (0,1)
Point p4 = (Rotate90Cw(runningForward))(samplePoint);   //must be (1,-4)
Point p4 = (Rotate90Cw(Rotate90Cw(forward)))(samplePoint);   //must be (0,1)
```

> I need a **single** `Rotate90Cw` function that can be applied on any `Translate` function and returns a proper `Translate` function. So the effect of applying `Rotate90Cw(forward)` on a point would be the same as applying `downward` on a point. And so on...

**I'm not going to make a separate `Rotate` function for every case (e.g. forwardRotated, downwardRotated and ...**

Comment: What about using extension methods imbrication the same way LINQ is designed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear that you actually want two delegates. It seems that really you want *one* delegate representing an arbitrary transformation from `Point` to `Point` - and you can then compose transformations. For example:

```
delegate Point Transform(Point input);

private static Transform Compose(Transform first, Transform second)
{
    return p => second(first(p));
}

Transform forward = p => new Point(p.X + 1, p.Y);
Transform rotate90 = p => new Point(p.Y, -p.X);
Transform forwardThenRotate = Compose(forward, rotate);
```

EDIT: It looks like what you actually want is a transform (taking in a transform) along the lines of:

- Apply the original transform to (0, 0)
- Rotate the result
- Translate the incoming point by that much

We can do that easily:

```
Transform forward = p => new Point(p.X + 1, p.Y);
Transform rotate90 = p => new Point(-p.Y, p.X);
Point forwardRotatedPoint = rotate90(forward(new Point(0, 0));

Transform forwardRotated = p => new Point(forwardRotatedPoint.X + p.X,
                                          forwardRotatedPoint.Y + p.Y);
```

As I said elsewhere though, you probably *actually* want a `Vector` type, which has `X` and `Y` components... then you could have several composable concepts:

- Creating a transformation (point to point) from a vector
- Rotating one vector to create another
- Composing transformations

Comment: Defining `Rotate` that accepts a point and returns another point do not make sense. It is expected for `Rotate` to get a vector, and here the Translate delegate is the most similar things to vector.

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad: I disagree completely - it's a rotation around the origin. I think it makes much more sense as a function on points and a function on arbitrary transformations. (If you really meant your `Translate` to be *just* a fixed translation, that should be using a vector-like type, not a delegate.)

Comment: You are correct in this case. But I'm not going to apply some map functions on a point one by one. I want to apply some transformed map functions on a point.

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad: I'm afraid you haven't made your requirements clear. I've provided one example of how you can compose transformations though - I'd hope that would be sufficient. If not, you really need to clarify your question.

Comment: I edited my post. By the way the output of your `Compose` is a `Point` not a `Transform` (as you write it).

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad: No, the output of `Compose` *is* a `Transform`. That's the whole point - it's composing two transformations to create a new transformation. That's why the return statement uses a lambda expression. I think you *are* confused about the concepts - the only form of composing a rotation with another arbitrary transformation is to rotate the result of applying the transformation... I suppose it could do so using the original point as the origin of the location, but that's a very special case.

Comment: Thank you. I test the output of `forwardRotated(new Point(1,1))`. It was (1,2) however I expect to be (1,0).

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad: Looks like I was doing an anti-clockwise rotation instead of a clockwise one - it was just the rotation part that was off. Try now. (And next time, if something doesn't work first time, try to understand each step of it - you should have been able to spot that the rotation transform was wrong for yourself.)

Answer (score 0):

I solve it this way (EDITED):

```
Translate Rotate90Cw(Translate moveFunction)
{
    return Rotate(moveFunction, Math.PI / 2.0);
}

Translate Rotate(Translate moveFunction, double angle)
{
    Point tempPoint = moveFunction(new Point(0, 0));
    double sin = Math.Sin(angle);
    double cos = Math.Cos(angle);
    return p => new Point(p.X + tempPoint.X * cos + tempPoint.Y * sin,
                           p.Y - tempPoint.X * sin + tempPoint.Y * cos);
}
```

Check if it is working:

```
Rotate90Cw(Rotate90Cw(runningForward))(new Point(1, 1)); //output: (-4,0.9999999)
Rotate90Cw(runningForward)(new Point(1, 1));             //output: (1,-4)
Rotate90Cw(backward)(new Point(1, 1));                   //output: (1,2)
Rotate90Cw(downward)(new Point(1, 1));                   //output: (0,1)
```

Comment: Right, that's basically the same approach as I used, just accepting an angle (although still oddly with 90 in the name) - but I still think you should have a different type for `Translate`. A translation isn't an arbitrary point to point transformation: it's the addition of a vector. So it would be better to represent it as a vector to start with.